# Link highlighting using jointjs

Tags: javascript, jointjs

Problem with the link highlighting like on the picture:
[image]

Have you any idea how to solve it?

Comment: would be helpful if you could post your code

Comment: Here is my code: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591189/how-to-highlight-all-element-relative-to-a-cell-on-diagram-when-using-jointjs

Comment: you want the link to be highlighted, but without that orange square right? Will increasing the width of the link's stroke value work?

Comment: Right. Increasing or decreasing the width of the link's stroke just changed the current width of the link. In my HTML markup, I have only 
`<g><path></path></g>` elements and it's rectangle area of the current link.

Comment: Probably I should define dia.LinkView element instead of the only dia.Link?

Comment: Do you have a custom Link definition? can you include the code please

Comment: Here is my Link define: https://jsfiddle.net/v010ho3q/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160283/discussion-between-sajith-dilshan-and-andrey-yakovenko).

Comment: Still doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlight method takes two parameters, the second of which allows you to specify the type of highlight. This is documented [here](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.CellView.prototype.highlight). One of the 'types' allowed is where you can specify a css class. You can define a class, and specify it here.

If that isn't enough, another option would be to extend linkView, and implement your own 'highlight' methods on that. Then provide this new linkView to the paper constructor as a template.